# Summarize results in a column format

Tags: r

I have a df like this:

```
df <- data.frame("Part" = c("y","z","y","z","x","y"), "Prod" = c("a","d","e","d","t","a"))
> df
    Part Prod
1    y    a
2    z    d
3    y    e
4    z    d
5    x    t
6    y    a
```

I want an output like this:

```
df2
   Part Prod
1    x    t
2    y    a
3    y    e
4    z    d
```

Actually I want a result that summarizes results without duplication in "Part" column. How to do this is R. Thanks

Comment: In your expected output `y` is duplicated in `Part`. Do you need `aggregate(Part~Prod, df, head, 1)` ?

Comment: Thanks Ronak it worked...Would this work for two columns or I can use it for more than two column, Suppose I have "Color" as third column, how would I aggregate that in a single df. Sorry I am a beginner in R. Thanks

Comment: I added an answer. It is easy to do it in `dplyr` if you have multiple columns by specifying all the columns in vars . If you have many such columns, you can specify them by position `summarise_at(1:5` or by range of columns `summarise_at(vars(Part:Color)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(Part, Color)~Prod, df, head, 1)
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Prod) %>% summarise_at(vars(Part, Color), first)
```